# Missing list view details when refreshing

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a list that list all of my customers. I refresh the list when I typed something in my search box. My problem is when I type something the list became unstable meaning the details for example the customer name is missing in some parts of the list.

I will show you what I mean.

This what the list looked like upon loading:

Image :

[image: Image 1]
This is what the list looked like when I tapped the item (I refreshed the list when I tapped an item) or search something:

[image: Image 2]

Now here is my code to list the page.

Here is my XAML Code:

```
<ListView SeparatorVisibility="Default" x:Name="lstActivity" ItemSelected="LstActivity_ItemSelected" ItemTapped="LstActivity_ItemTapped" HasUnevenRows="True">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Frame StyleClass="lstframe" CornerRadius="0" BorderColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False">
                                        <StackLayout StyleClass="lstContainer" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" StyleClass="lstActivityName" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ActivityDescription}">
                                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="SFProDisplay-Regular.ttf#SFProDisplay-Regular"/>
                                                        </OnPlatform>
                                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                                </Label>
                                                <Switch VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False" IsToggled="{Binding Selected}" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Here is my XAML.cs Code:

```
public void List_Activity()
    {
        try
        {
            var keyword = entSearchActivity.Text;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
            {
                var query = DefaultSettings.conn.QueryAsync<ActivityTable>("SELECT ActivityDescription, ActivityID, Selected FROM tblActivity ORDER BY ActivityDescription LIMIT 20");
                var resultCount = query.Result.Count;

                if (resultCount > 0)
                {
                    lstActivity.IsVisible = true;
                    result = query.Result;
                    lstActivity.ItemsSource = result;
                }
                else
                {
                    lstActivity.IsVisible = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var query = DefaultSettings.conn.QueryAsync<ActivityTable>("SELECT ActivityDescription, ActivityID, Selected FROM tblActivity WHERE ActivityDescription LIKE '%" + keyword +"%' ORDER BY ActivityDescription LIMIT 20");
                var resultCount = query.Result.Count;

                if (resultCount > 0)
                {
                    lstActivity.IsVisible = true;
                    result = query.Result;
                    lstActivity.ItemsSource = result;
                }
                else
                {
                    lstActivity.IsVisible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        }
    }
```

And here is my ActivityTable.cs:

```
[Table("tblActivity")]
public class ActivityTable
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string ActivityID { get; set; }
    public string ActivityDescription { get; set; }
    public string RecordLog { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastSync { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public int Deleted { get; set; }
    public int Checked { get; set; }
    public int Finished { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

My questions are:

1. What is/are the cause(s) of this?
2. How can I avoid this in the future?

Comment: Did you refresh the listview when you achieve the `SearchBar_TextChanged` method like this code?private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView.BeginRefresh();
            listView.ItemsSource = GetContacts(e.NewTextValue);
            listView.EndRefresh();
        }  You also could refer to this link https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/finding-nemo-implementing-xamarin-forms-searchbar/

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT No I didn't is that really necessary? and is that the cause why the data where missing?

Comment: You could make a test, this line just refresh data in listview.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I tried it still buggy behavior

Comment: Can you provide a simple demo to reproduce this issue？ Just populate static data(not from the database,you can create data by hardcode) into listview.

Comment: What I did is I store the list of activities (at least 20-30 items) to the local database (SQLite) then the rest of the code I've done is in the question.

Comment: I test your layout in VS, it could show the listview normally, What is your achievement in `ItemSelected="LstActivity_ItemSelected" ItemTapped="LstActivity_ItemTapped"` , please use the either of them, I advice you just use `ItemSelected`, because No matter how many times you perform ItemTapped,`ItemSelected` will be called in the end.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT in your testing its not buggy?  did you refresh the list every time you tapped an item?

Comment: You can this GIF of my demo, https://imgur.com/a/Q9ZK557, I did not know what is your achievement of `LstActivity_ItemSelected` or `LstActivity_ItemTapped`, Here is my code：https://github.com/851265601/searchBarDemo